# How can I implement Popupmenu below honeycomb

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, popupmenu

I want to implement popupmenu exactly as it is below honeycomb. I tried using floating contextual menu but it is not serving my purpose.Is there any library or something which I can use which will enable me to use popupmenu below honeycomb?.Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone give me a link to a cleaner example to use popupmenu in 2.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PopupMenuCompat** add in API level 4 with the support library appcompat.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/PopupMenuCompat.html)